# Php date and Hours issue

Tags: php, date, hour

I want to display the time between two datetime like this:

```
$diff = strtotime('2014-06-30 15:23:19') - strtotime('2014-06-30 15:20:16');
echo "time: ".date('H:i:s', $diff);
```

The result is :

```
time: 01:03:03
```

I don't understant why the hours display '01' ??
I tried with 'h:i:s' or 'g:i:s' but it doesn't work.

I would like this result:

```
time: 00:03:03
```

Comment: echo date(time(),"h:i:s");

Comment: Swap the order of the times. you're getting a negative value here because you are subtracting the future from the past.

Comment: my mistake, the order is good in my original code

Comment: When you do something like `date('H:i:s', $diff)`, you're asking php to format the time that's `$diff` seconds after the epoch (jan 1, 1970, UTC).  If you don't live in a time zone that's +0 GMT, you're not going to see the value you're expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the built in [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) functions of php.

You could do something like:

```
$time1 = new DateTime('2014-06-30 15:20:16');
$time2 = new DateTime('2014-06-30 15:23:19');

$diff = $time1->diff($time2);
```